# Pandas increase efficiency in merging dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

Here is the problem I am having.

I want to map team codes (contained in main df) with team names contained in `dfTeam`.

Here is a sample of main df:

```
              Game Code  Play Number  Period Number  Clock  Offense Team Code
0       690002820050901            1              1  900.0                690   
1       690002820050901            2              1    NaN                 28   
2       690002820050901            3              1    NaN                 28   
3       690002820050901            4              1    NaN                 28   
4       690002820050901            5              1    NaN                 28   
5       690002820050901            6              1    NaN                 28   
6       690002820050901            7              1  826.0                690   
7       690002820050901            8              1    NaN                690   
8       690002820050901            9              1    NaN                690
```

I want to change the columns like `Offense Team Code` with the team names using this dataframe, named `dfTeam`.

```
     Team Code                      Name  Conference Code
0            5                     Akron              875
1            8                   Alabama              911
2            9                       UAB            24312
3           28             Arizona State              905
4           29                   Arizona              905
```

Here is what I currently do, to merge the dataframes, change the column name and delete the columns I don't need:

```
teamDict = {'Home Team Code':'homeTeamName','Visit Team Code':'visitTeamName','Offense Team Code':'offenseTeamName','Defense Team Code':'defenseTeamName'}
for oldName,newName in teamDict.items():
    dfFULL = pd.merge(dfFULL,dfTeam,how='left',left_on=oldName,right_on='Team Code')
    dfFULL.rename(columns={'Name':newName},inplace=True)
    dfFULL.drop(['Conference Code','Team Code',oldName],axis=1,inplace=True)
```

This code works, but it is quite slow. My main dataframe has 130k or so rows. Is there a more efficient way to do it ?

Comment: Is `Team Code` the same as `Offense Team Code`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You basically want to use `dfTeam` as a dictionary to map `Team Codes` to `Names`. For each column, you can just perform the mapping.

```
d = dfTeam.set_index('Team Code').Name
for oldName,newName in teamDict.items():
    dfFULL[newName] = dfFULL[oldName].map(d)

# Then get rid of all old names
dfFull = dfFull.drop(columns=list(teamDict.keys()))
```

Comment: Yes, my issue is the run time of mapping the team codes to team names.

Comment: Yes, because you are performing 4 merges, renaming columns and then dropping. Mapping should be far faster in this case, since you're only matching on a single key value and need to change a single column value. In my experience, merging is better suited for matching on multiple keys, and/or joining multiple columns

Comment: Sorry, I think the original wording was a bit confusing